# grub bootloader + windows

Tags: grub2, bootloader

Okay so like 2 days ago I installed Ubuntu on my hp nootbook dm1 (it has no cd-drive). Then, today i deleted my linux partiton (not knowing about grub bootloader) and it just boots fine into windows now, no problems, but if i just startup my computer it says ''pres escape to go to bootsetup" (or something like this) when i do this i can chose from the optrions, "startop whit os maneger'', "startup from notebook harddrive", when i jsut pick os manneger it just does it job and boots in to windows, but when i click on ''startup from notebook harddrive'' i get the grub error, is there just any whay i just can delete grub? beacause my computer boots fine when i don't pres escape and select starup from harddrive. And maybe in the future i wanna install ubuntu again, does this mean i have to unistall grub first and then reinstaal ubuntu?

thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a Windows7 or Windows8 DVD, go to Repair Now -> TroubleShoot -> Command Prompt then type the following two commands:

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```